What is the "base address" in ifconfig output on some systems?
On the Busybox system I'm using, the output of busybox ifconfig -a includes a field for "Base address":
~ # busybox ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:D0:93:4D:AE:4F  
          inet addr:192.168.9.159  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:60 (60.0 B)  TX bytes:7136 (6.9 KiB)
          Base address:0xd000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:D0:93:4D:AE:50  
          inet addr:192.168.9.160  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1826 (1.7 KiB)  TX bytes:1678 (1.6 KiB)
          Base address:0x1000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:D0:93:4D:AE:51  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Base address:0xd000 

I have been unable to find any information on what this represents, despite extensive searching. Can someone tell me what it is, since it's clearly considered important and relevant enough to include in ifconfig output?

Each of the interfaces (eth0,eth1,eth2) is physically connected to the Network device/controller or Network Interface Cards(NICs) of your machine. So, in this case, the address say 0xd000 actually refers to the memory address of the network interface's I/O ports or the memory-mapped I/O (MMIO) space used by the network device.
The -a flag instructs the ifconfig command to output the information about all the network interfaces in the system. There are a couple of other methods (such ethtools,lspci, dmesg) to verify the base address.

Indeed, if you go back far enough you'll also find reference to the Interrupt number used for handling data i/o
